# Why does this Power Armor appear as X-01 but the parts state T-45?

Tags: fallout-4

I am level 53. When I go to S Boston Military Checkpoint, I can look through the cage and see that the power armor is X-01. When I unlock the terminal and open the cage it still appears as X-01 armor, but when I pull up its inventory it is actually T-45. It stays T-45 when I get into the armor, as well.

Has anyone else encountered this?

[image: screenshot T-45 armor]

Comment: Sounds like a bug. "It stays T-45 when I get into..." Does it switch to *look* like T-45? Did you try traveling in it or modding it at a power armor station?

Comment: Tried it again to be sure my memory is correct, and it _did_ switch to look like T-45. I fast traveled back to Sanctuary and transferred it to an armor station and it was still T-45.

Comment: I have come across this in a few places in fallout 4, This normally occurs when you find power Armour that is not set to a level until it is 'Discovered' in your case when you open the cage. The likely cause of this is you are deemed to low level for X-01 power armour. The normal level for that set of armour to spawn is about 35 in my experience

Comment: Except that I am level 53 (actually 58 now).

Comment: if that is the case then I would say this is most likely a bug with the game unfortunately, unless it is hard coded that there is always be that loot there and the Armour model just wasn't hard coded to display T-45 all the time. Sorry I couldn't be of more help

Comment: I wonder if this could be a bug regarding loading the cell off in the distance, but never getting close enough for it to render; so that it was a leveled suit, which was generated as T-45, but you bypassed it, and the first time it was able to actually render, it was still leveled, and looked like X-01.

Comment: @Zymus That sounds likely

Comment: @Zymus 
That makes the most sense of anything I've come up with so far. Any idea how close you need to be for level-dependent armor to set? I hadn't been close enough for the location to be "discovered" but it's certainly possible I'd been in the general region earlier in the game.

Comment: It occurs to me that your only asking "Has anyone else encountered this?". Do you wish to know how to change it back? Do you wish to know why it did this? Do you wish to know if there is a way to prevent this sort of issue happening in the future?

Comment: I'm also removing the video link, as when I click on it, it only takes me to an add page on tinypic.com

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the [*Cell reset*](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/6772/?) & [*Power Armor glitch*](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=561559484). Even if you'd made it home with the armor, if you ever exited it, fast traveled, saved (and quit?) and then went back to it, it'd be T-45 parts. Because you don't *own* the container that *is* the frame, it gets reset.

Go BUY a frame. Then treat yourself to whatever pieces you find at QAsmoke.

Related: [*Dude, Who Stole My Power Armor?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/249418/safe-and-secure-power-armor-garage/249521#249521)