# Why did all my cool power armors turn into rusty T-45's?

Tags: fallout-4

I had 5 sets of power armor in Sanctuary, and before I saved and stopped playing, I took out all the cores. However, when I started playing again **there were pieces missing and paint jobs had been reset back to default state.**

My Sanctuary is well guarded, with a 198 defense, and good happiness levels. I deleted my character, and started a new one, but the same thing happened again.

Why does this happen? How do I fix this?

Comment: This confuses me; How long did it take you to confirm the same problem with your "new" character? What platform are you playing on? Modifications / cheats ./ exploits? Is it possible your followers simply took the armor pieces? Followers will pick up random things **and this has nothing to do with their security or happiness**.

Comment: Title should be: *Dude, Who Stole My Power Armor?*

Comment: *"[WHY] when I started playing again, there were pieces missing, and paint jobs had been reset back to default state."* - That's basically a description of the *cell reset bug*. How much more narrower could the question be? @Timelord64 - If there's ANY other explanation, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Mazura, even with your edits, the question still does not match your reasoning. Once again, **Given that this is OPs problem, we need OP to add in the extra information. Not just you hijacking the question to fit your answer**.

Comment: Its also worth noting that if OP does not make the effort to update their question, themselves, they are also not likely to come back to accept the answer. A seperate question where you describe exactly what is happening, and go on to answer by explaining the bug and detailing fixes (which you can then personally confirm as the answer) would not only be more helpful, but it will earn you more rep

Comment: Replace *Sanctuary* with *Red Rocket*, delete the part about deleting the save, and I could've wrote exactly this. Until such time as the question is edited, and even then so (if not more so), I believe my answer is *useful*. Berating an answerer for your distaste of 1 reps is poor form IMO. I'm a rep hound for sure, just like the rest of us. But not on this one: I encountered this problem, as *many others have*, and had learned of the solution. I only wish to share it.

Comment: @Mazura, it is agreed in meta that answering a question that is going to be closed is not helpful. Quite on the contrary. As it is, enough users agree on the broadness to have closed this one.

Comment: @everyone who closed this: Do you play Fallout 4 and has this happened to you? Did you go online and learn how to fix or avoid it? Did you answer *yes* to all the previous questions? If you answered the last question with *no*, you don't have the authority to pass judgment on this question or its answers **based on its content**.

Comment: Seriously, this question should not have been closed for being "too broad" that's the most ridiculous thing ever.  This *is* the cell reset bug, and it's the *only* explanation for it.

Answer (score 6):

This is part of the [`cell reset bug`](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/6772/?). The current work around is to **only use power armor FRAMES that you BUY**. Not the ones that you find out in the world. Those are essentially containers that get 'reset' when the cell reloads, randomizing whatever the contents were (i.e., Super Duper Flame Painted T-60 parts) into basic rusty T-45 parts.

For what I gather, using console commands to set yourself as the 'owner' of a found frame [may prevent this](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=561559484) (FYI, the command is `setownership` and IIRC the player's ID is `14`). But better safe than sorry: KELO sells frames at Goodneighbor (just don't forget to take it home ;).

Another stop-gap is for it to always be worn when you save, either you or your current companion (they will exit it at some point, should you ever dismiss them, so keep that in mind).

I can't recall if this bug is present in the vanilla game, or if this happens to me because I've got mods installed. However, I can confirm that using purchased frames will keep you safe. On the plus side, you've got a few frames sitting around that will spawn free fusion cores for you.

Comment: Modders have reported that any change to a cell by an esm can trigger the reset. It's not my set, it's any mod that alters a cell in any way. *"Has anybody had this happen, before?"* YES (including myself but not anymore): Here's this same question on [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/492379159714310606/)

Comment: @Timelord64 - This answer is redundant because almost every mod on Nexus will warn you about this glitch.

Comment: That I can confirm it, is why indeed, there is no other answer for me. I've encountered this problem and fixed it. This is the workaround until a patch or the GECK comes out.

Comment: It might be the solution in your case, but that does not mean it will solve OPs problem. And if OP does not fix their question, it will not solve anybodies problems, as this question will be deleted.